# Configure Hibernate GenericGenerator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

in Spring+Hibernate application I am using GenericGenerator to generate PK in the following way:

```
@GenericGenerator(
    name = "gen",
    strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "MY_SEQUENCE"),
        @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1000")
    }
)
@GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
private Long id;
```

Is there any way to move parameters (sequence_name, initial_value) to configuration (persistenceContext.xml, properties file)?
I know I can subclass TableGenerator and do this in subclass. But I dont want to introduce new class that just takes parameters from one place and passes them to another place.

Spring v4.1.4.RELEASE, Hibernate v4.3.7.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an investigation - there is no such way, so I created a subclass of TableGenerator